# Why is my new SSD two times slower?

Tags: windows-7, ssd

Just bought Team XS2 ssd which tells that is should have 550mb/s read and 500mb/s write.
I'm only getting this:

[image]

Something seems to be wrong. There is a chance that this drive is a junk, but I hope that I did something wrong.

System:

- OS: W7x64
- CPU: 7 2600
- Memory: 8GB DDR3 (1833 MHz)
- SSD:120GB (split into 2 partitions)
- Board: p8z68-v

An interesting thing I noticed: I changed one of the options. Everything works fine, speed is near 500MB/s.Is this normal behavior?

[image]

Comment: What option did you change? What was it before? What is it now? What is the make and model of the SSD exactly? My bet is that 500MB/s is some kind of silly maximum rating (if data is infinitely compressible or something silly like that) that has no real-world value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If your SSD is slower using random data and fast using simple data like ones you have most likely an SSD using a SandForce chip. This chip uses online compression for all data. The maximum speed is only reached for data that can be compressed well.

The default test method of CrystalDiskMark uses random data which can be seen as the worst compressable data. Therefore you are not getting the benchmark results as expected.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I already figured it out, but hearing this from you added confidence. +1